# Insert a value into div parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom parameter in my div and I want to insert a value into this parameter using JS or JQuery.

```
<div id='test' data-sku=""></div>
```

Using JS or JQuery, how can I change/insert a value in data-sku?

Comment: `$("#test").data("sku", "my value here");`

Comment: @HemaNandagopal uhh, how's that relevant to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

jQuery (Check out the documentation for more usage examples: http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#test').attr('data-sku', 'my value')
```

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#test').setAttribute('data-sku', 'my value')
```

Comment: Should be `document.querySelector('#test').dataset.sku = "my value"`

Comment: `setAttribute` is a valid method on `Element`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.attr()` to set the value of a specific attribute of an element, like this:

```
$('#test').attr('data-sku', 'value');
```